# EOS reached when two threads read from datainputstream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, datainputstream

i am writing a program, where a program creates a thread which in turn reads from a socket, my problem is that when two threads are created, both read from the datainputstream. One thread reads properly while the other encounters an EOS and returns -1 as bytes read. i have synchronized my run method

Comment: You should only read from a stream using one thread or this is likely to lead to confusion. You don't need to synchronize read as it is thread safe already.  If you get an `-1` it means the stream ended.

Comment: The read method blocks till some stream is received right, in this case it reaches EOS and returns -1, which in turn stops the entire process

Comment: this problem happens only sometimes, and sometimes it works right.. this is not an issue which happens all the time.

Comment: A common mistake is to assume that the way you write() is the way you read().  Sometimes this is case, but a read() might read just one byte or it might read() the data of many write().  This is difficult to co-ordinate between threads.

Comment: i did a restart of my system and it worked, dont know if it will work when i restart the program though. 
Thanks, can you provide me some more details on what you said. ,
my read code is read(b,0,4) where b is a byte of length 4.

Comment: `int len = read(b, 0, 4);` The `len` can be 1,2,3 or 4. If you do more than one read, you have to synchronize access to ensure another thread won't read between. Using DataInputStream.readFully while hold the lock could help.

Comment: if (i=0)
read first four bytes, which is the header, save to headlen
else
{read(b,4,headlen) // which reads the rest of the data.
i++;}

tried a restart of the program and it failed, guess its a socket issue, but cannot figure out

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that you can't be sure that you will read 4 bytes in one read and you can't be sure you will read `headlen` in one read. It can work most of the time, but breaks randomly.

Comment: okay, so what should i do with it?? is there any solution...

Comment: The simplest solution is to use DataInputStream. You can use readInt() to read a whole `int` value, and you can use readFully(b, 0, len) to ensure you have read the entire length you expected. With DataOutputStream you have writeInt() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Must be because the first thread read the stream until EOF. Which is the expected behavior. If you want to split the reading e.g. swap the readers after 100 bytes, use [read(byte[] b, int off, int len)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)  otherwise read the data from one thread then share it.

Comment: I am using that with 0 and 4 as my offset and length, the threads are started simultaneously and are using the same program to read.. and also reading from the same socket, one thread receives the data after the other and the other thread responds to it using the same program

Comment: @Joy Could you post the source? Maybe the threads never yield, but it's hard to say without the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't make sense. You can't read a stream twice, whether sequentially or concurrently. In this case if thread A reads the first byte, thread B cannot read the first byte. If thread A reads all the bytes, thread B can't read any of them.

Comment: this problem happens only sometimes, and sometimes it works right.. this is not an issue which happens all the time. so i guess i can do that

Comment: @Joy at best your threads will alternately read random numbers of bytes from the stream. Whether they can make any sense of that is entirely up to how you program it. You would need to synchronize them against each other somehow, at a high enough level so you can be sure each thread has read what it wanted to read before allowing the other thread to read. The fact that you are getting random behaviour indicates that you haven't done that, and that you are indeed just guessing that it will work without that. It won't.